# select all rows if condition parameter is null

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

All rows

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

One row

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 3
```

I want to get all rows, how can i get ?

**example**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 0
```

Comment: Why can't you use the first example?

Comment: You can get all rows using first query

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly.Please clerify.

Comment: in procedure, i will use, if parameter is null, i want to get all rows.

Comment: just check in procedure if parameter is not null then add where condition otherwise don't add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a bit unclear, but I guess you are looking for a way to select all ids in case the given id parameter is zero.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = @id OR @id = 0;
```

Or with NULL instead of zero:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = @id OR @id IS NULL;
```

Comment: IFNULL(id,3); can be an alternative?

Comment: No. id is never null, as it is the primary key. (Or am I misunderstanding your database design and your question?) What I understand is that the parameter @id can be NULL. So `WHERE id = @id OR @id IS NULL` or with IsNull: `WHERE IFNULL(@id,id) = id`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all rows with parameter 0 then use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? OR ? = 0;
```

I hope that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table';

if (isset ($id)) {
  $query .= " WHERE id = $id";
}
```